# LinearLayout addView adds only one view

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

Im trying to add three views aligned horizontally in an LinearLayout but only one view is being shown; the first RED `circle` here is the code below:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        view_custom_loading = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        view_custom_loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view_custom_loading.setLayoutParams(linearParam);
        view_custom_loading.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.semi_trans));
        view_custom_loading.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        view_custom_loading.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        CircleView circle = new CircleView(getContext());
        circle.color = Color.RED;
        CircleView circle1 = new CircleView(getContext());
        circle1.color = Color.WHITE;
        CircleView circle2 = new CircleView(getContext());
        circle2.color = Color.BLUE;
        view_custom_loading.addView(circle);
        view_custom_loading.addView(circle1);
        view_custom_loading.addView(circle2);
        viewList.add(circle);
        viewList.add(circle1);
        viewList.add(circle2);
```

This is the CircleViews `onDraw` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(color);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 25, p);
    }
```

Comment: What is `CircleView`?

Comment: @Kevinrob I added the onDraw method theres no other code in the CircleView

Comment: @DGN there is no xml its all done through java

Comment: What output you are getting? Red circle filled the layout? or there is enough space for other circles and it just is invisible?

Comment: theres just a red circle and there is plenty of room for other views

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably your first circle has MATCH_PARENT width, that's why it's the only view you see. Change this parameter

**Update**

try

```
view_custom_loading.addView(circle, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Im setting the layoutparams to WRAP_CONTENT but they are still MATCH_PARENT